# Android Fragment Issues

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using Fragments to represents different views in my application.  I replace the fragments using the following code when navigating between views:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
ft.replace(R.id.main_linearlayout_fragmentcont, frag);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

I have run into a number of problems when rotating and the activity is reconstructed. I need to support old versions of android so android:configChanges="orientation" isn't an option. A lot of the issues are due to the nature of how Android saves Fragment state.

These are the problems I am running into:

1) The Fragment transitions don't remember my custom animations for pop events when they are restored automatically after a rotate. They do however remember my BackStack. I know I can write my own back handler that does a replace using animations and get rid of pop all together but I was wondering if there is a way to either reset the animation before calling popBackStack() or a way to have the FragmentManager remember the animations when it auto restores after rotate.

2) The other issue I have is that I have a bunch of child views (linearlayouts) in one of my top level fragment views that contain their own fragments.  These child views are created and populated programmatically.  When my fragment is recreated after rotation, I programmatically reconstruct the child views in onCreateView of the Fragment Object and I end up with duplicate fragments under each of the child views (1 - I create programmatically and 1 - Android Fragments create from restore).  I am assuming this is because I programmatically reconstruct the child views after rotation with the same id. Is there a way to prevent Fragments from being restored?  When does Android inject the Fragments from savedState into these views I construct programmatically?  How would I prevent this from happening?

3) The above replace code seems to fire onCreateView multiple times for my frag (Fragment) object.  This is without rotation and happens when I run the above code only once.  Is there a reason that onCreateView of a Fragment would be called multiple times with the above code?

Questions about Fragments:
  1) Can I prevent Android from auto restoring fragments when an activity is reconstructed?  How would I go about this?  Is it based on the ID of the LinearLayout?  Could I call removeAllViews of the LinearLayout containing the fragment onStop?  That way the view doesn't exist when it saves?

2) Is there a way to add a Fragment to a LinearLayout that I have a reference to but that doesn't have an ID?  It appears the Fragment add, replace APIs require an int ID.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) This bug exists in the Android platform and support library 18. [Issue 25994](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25994) Fragment animations are not being saved across configuration changes.  A workaround requires a patch to the support library.  If this is an essential feature of your app then you could either patch the library or avoid child fragments in favor of deeper activity coupling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) if you find out how let me know, I'm also pissed off by that

2) you're probably calling `add` on the FragmentTransaction inside the top level fragment, but the restore operation is also adding, so duplicates! option 1. Use `replace` instead. option 2. (preferred) Check `if(savedInstances==null) { // do transaction } else { //let the system rebuilt it itself}`

3) If you're changing the layout (by calling add or replace) of a view that is a part of a fragment, the manager call the method to creates the view again. I'm still not sure if that is a bug or a feature, and if it's a feature why it is. If you find out let me know

1) (supposed to be 4, no?) don't mess with the layouts, if u want to remove, remove them using `while(popBackStackImmediatly){}`, but if you go deeper and understand what the system is doing, usually there's no reason to not let it do it automatically.

2) (supposed to be 5, no?) if you have a reference you have the id [View.getId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29)

happy coding!

Comment: 1) I thought I was crazy for not being able to figure it out as I thought it had to be possible.
2) I will try replace but I think the restored fragment is getting added after I create programmatically. I don't have access to savedInstances in this particular case and it happens on a button click in the future.  I would prefer to not save the savedInstances and wire that through to this code.  I am thinking that I might try to generate a unique id per each newly constructed view.  I am hoping that will solve the issue.
3) thanks for the details.

Comment: 4) Agreed. It just seems frustrating to not have as much control as I would like with Fragments.
5) I didn't want to assign an ID to the view but I don't think I can do this with fragments.

Comment: 2) if you want to block the system from re-creating I reckon the best option is to include a TAG on every fragment and `if(savedInstances!=null) findFragmentByTag->remove`, this also works for item 4. 5) AFAIK, if you don't assign an ID to the view, the system auto-generates one on runtime and you can access it via `myLinearLayout.getId();`. I might be wrong on this last one, gotta test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are change the orientation of device then check the validation in activity and it also manage the fragment with stack so your flow not damage in that case.

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) {

   mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 

   mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

   FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();

   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```